# How to recreate an image from the binary string downloaded from a REST API

Tags: python, image, rest, download, binary

I would like to recreate a .png file sent from a Flask server.
If I GET in a browser the file downloads and I can view it.
If I GET it from python requests I have problems saving the file and I can never view it because the format seems to be broken.

Client:

```
req = requests.get(URL + "/image/file.png")

with open("recv.png", "wb") as f:
    print(req.text)
    f.write(req.text.encode())
```

Server:

```
@app.route("/image/<string:path>")
def get(path):
    return send_from_directory("images", path, mimetype="image/png", as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Base64 encoding with multipart http request:-

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
```

Comment: It's not about the server though. Like I said in my browser I can download the file just fine.

I'm having problems with a client who is not using a browser but who is using a python script (Check my edits in the question)